# Prove $(Ma)\times(Mb)=(\det M)(M^{-1})^T(a\times b)$ for matrix transformation $M$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I wanted to prove $(Ma)\times(Mb)=(\det M)(M^{-1})^T(a\times b)$ where the formula could be found here [wiki's cross product page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties) However, I had a hard time counting the index, and I was wondering if there's any easier way to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equal because
\begin{aligned}
\left[(\det M)(M^{-1})^T(a\times b)\right]\cdot Mc
&=(\det M)(a\times b)\cdot M^{-1}Mc\\
&=\det(M)(a\times b)\cdot c\\
&=\det(M)\det[a,b,c]\\
&=\det[Ma,Mb,Mc]\\
&=(Ma\times Mb)\cdot Mc
\end{aligned}
for every vector $c$.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of the determinant, $\epsilon_{ijk}M_{il}M_{jm}M_{kn}=(\det M)\epsilon_{lmn}$. Multiplying both sides by $a_lb_m$, $[M^T(Ma\times Mb)]_n=(\det M)(a\times b)_n$, i.e. $M^T(Ma\times Mb)=(\det M)a\times b$. The desired result then follows from $(M^T)^{-1}=(M^{-1})^T$.